Group by on entire dataframe vs group by on subset of columns of dataframe
I'm working in a codebase where I see a lot of groupby usage like this that operates on a subset of the columns of df
df[cols].groupby(some_column).nunique()[column2extract]

where cols includes some_column and column2extract, and in most coses cols = [some_column, column2extract]
Functionally, I think this is equivalent to
df.groupby(some_column).nunique()[column2extract]

Is there some advantage to the former that I should be aware of? I see this often throughout this codebase, and I feel I may be missing something.
Actually, I think the 2 are only equivalent when cols = [some_column, column2extract] and not necessarily equivalent when cols contain additional columns

First thing, (...).groupby(some_column).nunique()[column2extract] seems like a waste of resources. You would compute the nunique for all columns, then index those of interest.
This should be:
(...).groupby(some_column)[column2extract].nunique()

So, df[cols].groupby(some_column).nunique()[column2extract] might be better if cols is [column2extract, some_column], but still an unnecessarily complicated syntax.
The only advantage of df[cols].groupby(some_column).(...) is if some_column is a external Series and not a column name that is part of df.
Thus, in my opinion, the best would be:
df.groupby(some_column)[column2extract].nunique()

If you want a Series as output, this is also an option:
df[column2extract].groupby(df[some_column]).nunique()


Actually I'm looking at this again and isn't df.groupby(some_column).nunique()[column2extract] and df.groupby(some_column)[column2extract].nunique() actually different? In the former, the nunique() is computing the number of distinct combinations of all the columns for each group, and in the latter, it's simply computing the number of distinction column2extract values for each group?

oh i see. nunique() in the former case appears to operate on each column independent of the other columns. I misunderstood

@jinkins yes, most groupby methods operate independently per column.
